# Dpkg command fails while installing packages due to invalid user error

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to install packages using dpkg command, in particular cuda-8. 
Whenever I run the command, it fails with the error. This goes on infinitely till I press `Clt + C` to end the tool.

```
Setting up tta...
chown: invalid user: ‘ttasys:ttaserv’
chown: invalid user: ‘ttasys:ttaserv’
chown: invalid user: ‘ttasys:ttaserv’
.
.
.
.
.
dpkg: error processing package tta (--configure):
```

Because of this, I am unable to install or remove packages from Ubuntu Software center as well. Everytime I do, it will throw the same error and fail. Please suggest appropriate steps to get out of this trouble. I have a lot of packages which are half installed and want to clear them up, but can't do because of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reference in the installation instructions regarding running cuda-8 under the user ttasys, however the following command should get you past this log jam:

```
sudo adduser --system --group --no-create-home ttasys
```

Comment: I tried installing an external tool called Oracle Secure Global Desktop (SGD), which had a file called ttatcc. I am not sure if this caused the trouble.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?  If you have questions about the Oracle Desktop causing problems, you can always remove it, get your system stabilized and then if you like, reinstall SGD.  It's usually not a good idea to install too much software too quickly.  Install, test, reboot and if all is OK, install the next big package.  Repeat.

Comment: Your approach worked, but I am not much satisfied. And I am unable to remove that software as well, which is the bad part. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Probably best to ask a new question since you now have a different problem.  Glad my answer worked for you!